# trying to dynamically append svg group with d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to dynamically append a group to an svg.  I'm currently selecting an existing group from the svg as shown below:

```
var regions = d3.select(document.getElementById('imgMap').contentDocument).select('#cellregionnode').selectAll('circle')[0];
```

Now I'm trying to dynamically add a group to the same svg but I'm encountering issues for some reason.

```
var myNewGroup = d3.select(document.getElementById('imgMap').contentDocument).append('g').attr('id','myNewGroup');
```

However, attempting this code returns the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of null
    at window.onerror (systemjs.js:8)

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createElementNS' of null
    at XMLDocument.t (d3.v3.min.js:1)
    at XMLDocument.<anonymous> (d3.v3.min.js:3)
    at Array.Co.select (d3.v3.min.js:3)
    at Array.Co.append (d3.v3.min.js:3)
    at setGlobals (DataLoader.js:40)
    at Object.success (DataLoader.js:17)
    at i (app.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (app.min.js:2)
    at A (app.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (app.min.js:4)
```

Any idea what might be causing this error or how to fix?

Comment: Why are you doing this? What are you trying to do with this code? To append a group anywhere you just do `selector.append("g")`.